# Normalize z-axis values onto [0, 1] when using vis.gam for a mgcv GAM

Tags: r, plot, normalization, gam, mgcv

I have just finished fitting a GAM using the `mgcv` package (I will call this model `gam1.5`). I have been playing around with the `vis.gam` function and I have a question I have not been able to solve.

I would like to normalize the fitted values of my model so when I use `vis.gam`, the z-axis has limits [0, 1].

My idea was to apply the normalization formula in the `$fitted.values` of my GAM model as follows:

```
gam1.5$fitted.values<-(gam1.5$fitted.values-min(gam1.5$fitted.values))/(max(gam1.5$fitted.values)-min(gam1.5$fitted.values))
```

However, when I run the `vis.gam`, it does not change the scale of the z-axis. I was wondering if I am applying the normalization formula to the incorrect object (a different one to `$fitted.values`) within the GAM object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Because `vis.gam` is based on `predict.gam` and your change to `$fitted.values` has no effect!

In fact, you can't achieve your goal with `vis.gam`. This function simply produces a plot and returns nothing for user to later reproduce the plot (unless `vis.gam` is called again). This means, we will need to work with `predict.gam`. Here are the basic steps.

- Set up a 2D grid / mesh. You may want to use `exclude.too.far` to filter data far away from training data to avoid ridiculous spline / polynomial extrapolation (as `vis.gam` does);
- Construct a new data frame `newdat` (from the above grid) and call `oo <- predict.gam(gam1.5, newdat, type = "terms")` to obtain term-wise prediction. This is a matrix. You need to retain only the column associated with the 2D smooth you want to plot. Let's say this column is stored into a vector `z`;
- Augment `z` into a matrix by padding `NA` for those *too far* data.
- Normalize `z` onto `[0, 1]`.
- Use `image` or `contour` to produce the plot yourself.

Ideally we should take an example (maybe from `?vis.gam`) and work through the above steps. However, you returned to me saying that you quickly sorted out the problem using `predict.gam`. Then I will not add examples for demonstration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Finally, I have used predict.gam to create a new dataframe and normalize the values in this new dataframe and later plot a 3d surface using wireframe() as you suggested!